# ThreadLocal<Socket> what if connection lost?

Tags: .net

I have fairly theoretical question regarding `ThreadLocal<T>`, my T can become unusable due to events that occasionally take place in surrounding world, such as connection loss. Any ideas on how to reset ThreadLocal value, relative to a thread where the object got unusable, without reseting whole `ThreadLocal<T>` object?

By the way

- My context is ASP.NET MVC, I do something similar to `ThreadLocal<DatabaseConnection>` (There are good reasons to do that in my case)
- So, solutions that make user looking at exception like "Bang! Your program faulted, cuz developer that written this program is a braindead zombie" are not an option...

Have a good time with this puzzle and thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Imagine a web server which has a pool of 8 threads that handles 512 client requests per minute, I'm using the above solution to limit the amount of open connections to 8 connections per minute, rather than creating 512 of them within same period of time...

**EDIT:** Here is the source related to my problem, I'm asking my self a question "What if connection to database lost in some specific thread" how would I recreate and RE-set it inside ThreadLocal:

**public class EloqueraThreadLocalInstanceFactory**

```
public class EloqueraThreadLocalInstanceFactory
{
    Property<DB> database;

    private DB CreateInstance()
    {
        var db = new DB(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            db.OpenDatabase(DatabaseName);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            db.CreateDatabase(DatabaseName);
            db.OpenDatabase(DatabaseName);
        }

        return db;
    }

    public EloqueraThreadLocalInstanceFactory(String connectionString, String databaseName, params Action<DB>[] initializers)
    {
        DatabaseName = databaseName;
        ConnectionString = connectionString;

        database = new ThreadLocalPropertyValue<DB>(CreateInstance, initializers);
    }

    public String DatabaseName { get; private set; }
    public String ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public DB GetInstance()
    {
        return database;
    }
}
```

**public class Property { ... }**

```
public class Property<T>
{
    private PropertyValue<T> propertyValue;

    protected virtual void OnAfterSet()
    {
        if (AfterSet != null)
        {
            AfterSet(this, null);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnBeforeGet(EventArgs<T> eventArgs)
    {
        if (BeforeGet != null)
        {
            BeforeGet(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnBeforeSet(CancellableEventArgs<PropertyValue<T>> e)
    {
        if (BeforeSet != null)
        {
            BeforeSet(this, e);
        }
    }

    public Property()
    {

    }
    public Property(PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        this.propertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        propertyValue = null;
    }

    // IsSet is required to be implemented via method to prevent it from being serialized
    public Boolean IsSet() 
    {
        return propertyValue != null;
    }

    // Value property is required for serialization purposes
    public T Value
    {
        get { return Get(); }
        set { Set(new StaticPropertyValue<T>(value)); }
    }

    protected void SetRaw(PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        this.propertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    protected virtual T Get()
    {
        var eventArgs = new EventArgs<T>(propertyValue.GetPropertyValueInternal());

        OnBeforeGet(eventArgs);

        return eventArgs.Value;
    }
    protected virtual void Set(PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        var eventArgs = new CancellableEventArgs<PropertyValue<T>>(propertyValue);

        OnBeforeSet(eventArgs);

        this.propertyValue = propertyValue;

        if (!eventArgs.Cancel)
        {
            SetRaw(propertyValue);

            OnAfterSet();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler AfterSet;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<T>> BeforeGet;
    public event EventHandler<CancellableEventArgs<PropertyValue<T>>> BeforeSet;

    public static implicit operator T(Property<T> property)
    {
        return property == null ? default(T) : property.Get();
    }

    public static implicit operator Property<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Property<T>(new StaticPropertyValue<T>(value));
    }
    public static implicit operator Property<T>(Func<T> value)
    {
        return new Property<T>(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(value));
    }
    public static implicit operator Property<T>(PropertyValue<T> value)
    {
        return new Property<T>(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator PropertyValue<T>(Property<T> property)
    {
        return property.propertyValue;
    }

    /***************************************************************************************************/

    public static Property<T> operator <=(Property<T> property, Func<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Set(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >=(Property<T> property, Func<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.Set(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <=(Property<T> property, PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Set(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >=(Property<T> property, PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.Set(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <=(Property<T> property, LazyPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Set(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >=(Property<T> property, LazyPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.Set(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <=(Property<T> property, StaticPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Set(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >=(Property<T> property, StaticPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.Set(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

    /***************************************************************************************************/

    public static Property<T> operator <(Property<T> property, Func<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetRaw(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >(Property<T> property, Func<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.SetRaw(new LazyPropertyValue<T>(propertyValue));

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <(Property<T> property, PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetRaw(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >(Property<T> property, PropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.SetRaw(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <(Property<T> property, LazyPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetRaw(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >(Property<T> property, LazyPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.SetRaw(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

    public static Property<T> operator <(Property<T> property, StaticPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetRaw(propertyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Property<T>(propertyValue);
        }

        return property;
    }
    public static Property<T> operator >(Property<T> property, StaticPropertyValue<T> propertyValue)
    {
        property.SetRaw(propertyValue);

        return property;
    }

}

public abstract class PropertyValue<T>
{
    protected abstract T GetPropertyValue();

    internal T GetPropertyValueInternal()
    {
        return GetPropertyValue();
    }
}

public class InitializablePropertyValue<T> : PropertyValue<T>
{
    private Func<T> func;
    private Action<T>[] initializers;

    public InitializablePropertyValue(Func<T> func, params Action<T>[] initializers)
    {
        if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
        if (initializers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("initializers");

        this.func = func;
        this.initializers = initializers;
    }

    protected override T GetPropertyValue()
    {
        var result = func();

        foreach (var initializer in initializers)
        {
            initializer(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class StaticPropertyValue<T> : PropertyValue<T>
{
    private T value;

    public StaticPropertyValue(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    protected override T GetPropertyValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static implicit operator StaticPropertyValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new StaticPropertyValue<T>(value);
    }
}

public class LazyPropertyValue<T> : InitializablePropertyValue<T>
{
    private Lazy<T> lazy;

    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory)
        : base(valueFactory)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, false);
    }
    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory, Boolean isThreadSafe)
        : base(valueFactory)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, isThreadSafe);
    }
    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
        : base(valueFactory)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, mode);
    }

    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory, params Action<T>[] initializers)
        : base(valueFactory, initializers)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, false);
    }
    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory, Boolean isThreadSafe, params Action<T>[] initializers)
        : base(valueFactory, initializers)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, isThreadSafe);
    }
    public LazyPropertyValue(Func<T> valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode mode, params Action<T>[] initializers)
        : base(valueFactory, initializers)
    {
        this.lazy = new Lazy<T>(base.GetPropertyValue, mode);
    }

    public Boolean IsInitialized
    {
        get { return lazy.IsValueCreated; }
    }

    protected override T GetPropertyValue()
    {
        return lazy.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator LazyPropertyValue<T>(Func<T> value)
    {
        return new LazyPropertyValue<T>(value);
    }
}

public class ThreadLocalPropertyValue<T> : InitializablePropertyValue<T>
{
    ThreadLocal<T> threadLocal;

    public ThreadLocalPropertyValue(Func<T> func, params Action<T>[] initializers)
        : base(func, initializers)
    {
        this.threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<T>(base.GetPropertyValue);
    }

    protected override T GetPropertyValue()
    {
        return threadLocal.Value;
    }
}

public class DynamicPropertyValue<T> : PropertyValue<T>
{
    Func<T> func;

    public DynamicPropertyValue(Func<T> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }

    protected override T GetPropertyValue()
    {
        return func();
    }
}
```

Comment: ThreadLocal *is* per thread - I don't get what "reset .. relative to a thread" means.

Comment: There are dozens of connections to my web site, I'm using special key/value database that doesn't know how to manage connections wisely, so I need to manage connections by my self, so I want to make 1 connection per thread, thats all :)

Comment: Okay, that's fine, so where/why does ThreadLocal fit in? I would suggest *not* using it. Simply "give" object ownership to a thread.

Comment: IIS creates it's own pool of threads that handle connections, I don't want to create a connection to a database on "Per request" basis, I want to create a connection to a database once per application load

Comment: @Lu4 This is why DB  *Connection Pool* exists.

Comment: .. so why ThreadLocal and not just "global"? (I'm still lost as to what ThreadLocal is doing here :D)

Comment: Exactly an XY problem. "*You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.*"

Comment: I'm not using SQL Server, connection pool technique doesn't exist for every known database, I'm using Eloquera, I have to pool connections by my self...

Comment: @Lu4 To implement your own pool, you still don't need ThreadLocal.

Comment: It is not clear what other than ThreadLocal do I need then :)

Comment: @Lu4 For ex, you may need a class with thread-safe static methods like `GetConnection` and `ReturnConnection`

Comment: That's perfectly clear that I need those methods, my questions was related specifically to an aspects of their implementation. In other words how should I implement such pooling when there is no access to Eloquera source code and their wrapper isn't threadsafe and not pooling connections

Comment: @Lu4 `. In other words how should I implement` Theoretical answers don't seem what you are looking for. So what do you expect from us. Write it for you?

Comment: I see this chat is going into wrong direction...